# Converting a C++ String Class to a Python String

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a C++ class that is able to output strings in normal ASCII or wide format.  I want to get the output in Python as a string.  I am using SWIG (version 3.0.4) and have read the SWIG documentation.  I believe I need to use the typemap construct to achieve my goal.  I have written the following:

```
%typemap(out) my_namespace::MyString *
{
  $result = PyString_AsString($1);
}
```

with no success. When I try to access a C++ string from Python, I get the following output:

```
<Swig Object of type 'MyString *' at 0x02B6FC68>
```

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I use pyboost for C++/python interfaces and is amazing and easy to do that. If you can, I recommend it. A simply std::string is automatically mapped to python string. In your case, may be any solution is to define a

> __str __

method for the object or directly pass a char* (I see that in swig docs but I never followed this way).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the correct solution was:

```
%typemap(out) my_namespace::MyString &
{
    $result = PyString_FromFormat($1->c_str());
}
```

Not very intuitive, but it works.

Comment: You should be using `PyObject* PyString_FromString(const char *v)` rather than from format.